# REST api does not Return Values in SmartObject tester

Tags: c#, sql-server, rest, k2

I Have a Problem. 
I have a REST Api thats working pretty well. Does everything i want it to Do. Now when I Load it inside Postman, it works fine Like this

[REST on Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uuff0.png)

Now it works fine in Postman, Should i then move it into the Smartobject Tester, it does not show anything. Looking Like this in Smartobject Tester

[REST API in SmartObject Tester](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeDEk.png)

Could it be because I didnt make it to Return the Values in Json?

**PS**

My code Looks somewhat Like this ::

```
using EmployeeRESTAPI.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace EmployeeRESTAPI.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeDBController : ApiController
    {
        string MyconnectionString = "Data Source=DLX;Initial Catalog=EmployeeDB;Integrated Security=True";
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<EmployeeDB> Get()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MyconnectionString);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            con.Open();

            string query = "select* from [EmployeeDB].[dbo].[EmployeeTable]";
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            List<EmployeeDB> empdb = new List<Models.EmployeeDB>(dt.Rows.Count);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow empdbrecord in dt.Rows)
                {
                    empdb.Add(new ReadEmployee(empdbrecord));
                }
            }
            return empdb;
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public IEnumerable<EmployeeDB> Get(string accountnumber)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MyconnectionString);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            con.Open();

            string query = "select * from [EmployeeDB].[dbo].[EmployeeTable] where accountnumber = '" + accountnumber + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            List<EmployeeDB> empdb = new List<Models.EmployeeDB>(dt.Rows.Count);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow empdbrecord in dt.Rows)
                {
                    empdb.Add(new ReadEmployee(empdbrecord));
                }
            }
            return empdb;
        }

        // POST api/<controller>
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/<controller>/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<controller>/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to consider the Headers that you used in your postman request.

Comment: @jegtugado, GET and POST requests you mean?

Comment: Yes. Headers such as Content-Type and Accept can determine a successful request.

Comment: Can you Pls show me how in my Code. I am fairly new to most of these things

Comment: In postman you have headers like Fullname and TelephoneNumber.  Where are the headers in REST?

Comment: @jdweng, Those are input parameters to use in filtering basically from a REST api

Comment: The fact that you can successfully test your APIs in Postman means your code is fine as it is. In your SmartObject tester tool, look for a way to add http request headers like the one you used in Postman. That tool looks old and to be honest I think only a few knows how it works and I'm not one of them.

Comment: @jegtugado i would like you to reference the images i showed, i do not have enough rights to post images, else you would have seen and understood what i mean

Comment: try your request in various browsers, with curl, etc. I think you will find it works with everything except the apparently not-so-SmarObject. On another topic, are you aware of the SQL injection vulnerability with your code?

Comment: The server expects the headers and may not return a valid response when the headers are missing.